# How to interpret combinations of "value(s) of measurement(s)"

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number

I can never be quite sure how to choose between the four combinations of phrases of the form "value(s) of measurement(s)".

In my specific case, I am writing about measuring multiple values from multiple sensors, such as measuring the temperature in different rooms in a house multiple times during the day.

For example, which one is more appropriate to say?

- "I measured the temperature of all rooms in the house"
- "I measured the temperatures of all rooms in the house"

The two other combinations may not make much sense in the above case, I had other cases where I had to consider all four combinations.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you have measured the "temperatures" of all rooms, it implies that you measured more than one temperature per room. For instance, the day and the night temp. or the temp. on the floor and the ceiling. So you get 2 values per room.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is not what a native speaker would say. I think that your first example is clear, but if you wanted definitely to rule out the idea that what you measured was some kind of single average temperature, then you could say "I measured the temperature of each room in the house". Although in that example it would be quite unnecessary, you could make it extra clear by  inserting "individually".

If there is a risk of misunderstanding a few extra words may remove it.